# WPF Dependency property not firing with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, icommand

I have a class:

```
public class CommandHamburgerMenu : FrameworkElement, ICommand
{
    public HamburgerMenuItem Item
    {
        get { return (HamburgerMenuItem)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), typeof(CommandHamburgerMenu), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemChanged)));

    private static void ItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommandHamburgerMenu commandHamburgerMenu = (CommandHamburgerMenu)d;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.Item != null)
        {
            if (this.Item == MainWindow.Instance.itemHome) MessageBox.Show("Home item");
            else if (this.Item == MainWindow.Instance.itemSearch) MessageBox.Show("Search item");
            else MessageBox.Show("Other");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

and the XAML code:

```xml
<HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu MenuIconColor="Black" SelectionIndicatorColor="Black" MenuItemForeground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ColorHighlight, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu.Background>
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="itemHome" Icon="Assets/home.png" Text="Home">
        <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem.SelectionCommand>
            <commands:CommandHamburgerMenu Tag="{Binding ElementName=itemHome, Path=Text}" />
        </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem.SelectionCommand>
    </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem>
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="itemSearch" Icon="Assets/search.png" Text="Search">
        <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem.SelectionCommand>
            <commands:CommandHamburgerMenu Tag="{Binding ElementName=itemHome, Path=Text}" />
        </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem.SelectionCommand>
    </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem>
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="itemFavorite" Icon="Assets/favorite.png" Text="Likes"/>
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="itemList" Icon="Assets/list.png" Text="Lists"/>
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="itemPerson" Icon="Assets/person.png" Text="Profile"/>
</HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu>
```

HamburgerMenu is a control taken from [here](https://github.com/alicanerdogan/HamburgerMenu), property SelectionCommand is a dependency property of ICommand type, it's firing by click on hamburger menu item. But when app starts, Item property is null, and ItemChanged not firing. It fires only after manually setting Item property from code behind. Why?

Comment: so if anyone wants to know the solution... here it is:
foreach (HamburgerMenu.HamburgerMenuItem item in hamburgerMenu.Content)
{
item.SelectionCommand = new CommandHamburgerMenu(item);
}

Comment: You can't bind to an ElementName because the command is not in the same element tree...so you'd better set the property programmatically or re-Think your approach.

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyChangedCallback` of a dependency property is only called when the value of the dependency property is actually changed.

It is not called once initially for the default value of the dependency property.

But you could of course call the method yourself, for example in the constructor of the class:

```
public class CommandHamburgerMenu : FrameworkElement, ICommand
{
    public CommandHamburgerMenu()
    {
        ItemChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(CommandHamburgerMenu.ItemProperty, null, null));
    }

    public HamburgerMenuItem Item
    {
        get { return (HamburgerMenuItem)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), typeof(CommandHamburgerMenu), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemChanged)));

    private static void ItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommandHamburgerMenu commandHamburgerMenu = (CommandHamburgerMenu)d;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.Item != null)
        {
            if (this.Item == MainWindow.Instance.itemHome) MessageBox.Show("Home item");
            else if (this.Item == MainWindow.Instance.itemSearch) MessageBox.Show("Search item");
            else MessageBox.Show("Other");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the Item is still null. When I creating the string dependency property and set it like Property="Value", change event fires immediatly on app starts

Comment: Yes, the callback will be invoked whenever it is set to something other than null.

Comment: Where are you setting the Item property?

Comment: <commands:CommandHamburgerMenu MyProperty="test" Tag="{Binding ElementName=itemHome, Path=Text}" />
private static void MyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.NewValue.ToString());
        }
it showing "test" when app starts

Comment: the issue that Tag property is null when app starts, but I set the Tag property to Tag="{Binding ElementName=itemHome, Path=Text}", so the Tag must be "Home"

Comment: How is the Tag related to your callback for the Item property...?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I confused one thing and another. Forget about the Tag :) Call it Item - the Item is a HamburgerMenuItem that passing to this Item property.

Comment: Where is the binding?

Comment: Here it is. The XAML in question above is litle wrong, but I fixed it here:

<HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="itemHome" Icon="Assets/home.png" Text="Home">
        <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem.SelectionCommand>
            <commands:CommandHamburgerMenu Item="{Binding ElementName=itemHome}" />
        </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem.SelectionCommand>
    </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem>

Comment: The SelectionCommand property is supposed to be set to an ICommand...What is a commands:CommandHamburgerMenu?

Comment: public class CommandHamburgerMenu : FrameworkElement, ICommand
this class implements ICommand, so it can be passed to SelectionCommand